# Cannot delete any K8s resource

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

Here's my situation: I have deployed some k8s resources via docker stack liek this:

`docker stack deploy --compose-file /path/to/docker-compose.yml mystack`

`docker stack services mystack`

Now, I want to delete some of those resources, however, any resource I attempt to delete simply restarts itself immediately.

I have tried to delete the pods, corresponding replica sets, deployments and services but whatever resource I deleted, it restarted itself within a second.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you deleting the deployment? you should use: ```docker stack rm```

Comment: Why can't I just use `kubectl delete deployment <deployment_name>`  in order to, let's say, only remove a specific deployment?

Comment: I am not very fimiliar with docker stack, but it seems it keeps some kind of state, and makes sure everything is deployed, why not directly use kubectl for deploying the app in the first place?

Comment: It was an attempt to deploy my docker-compose.yml without the necessity of re-writing all the stuff.

Btw thanks! It worked with `docker stack rm`

Comment: It's the `docker swarm`. You can't use `kubectl` in a swarm. Also the purpose of docker service is to create the container, if deleted or stopped. Create a kubernetes cluster, deploy and then delete with kubectl.

Comment: But I can use kubectl to get the deployed resources. I do not think that you can definitely not use kubectl. However, the deletion part seems not to work so you're right in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use docker stack to delete the stack

```
docker stack rm <stack-name>
```